# roll hourly data forward by one year and account for differences in datetimeindex

Tags: python, pandas

I have hourly data for many years which looks like this in terms of format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]},
     index = [pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:00'),
     pd.Timestamp('20130101 10:00:00'),
     pd.Timestamp('20130101 11:00:00'),
     pd.Timestamp('20130101 12:00:00'),
     pd.Timestamp('20130101 13:00:00')])
```

But I have data from 2013 until end of 2019. I would like to roll data forward by year, so lets say I want all values from 2013 rolled to 2014 and account for timestamp differences (so if its a leap year it should still work). Result should look like this:

```
dfnew = pd.DataFrame({'Value': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]},
        index = [pd.Timestamp('20140101 09:00:00'),
                pd.Timestamp('20140101 10:00:00'),
                pd.Timestamp('20140101 11:00:00'),
                pd.Timestamp('20140101 12:00:00'),
                pd.Timestamp('20140101 13:00:00')])
```

EDIT:

if I roll forward from say 2015 to 2016 then the number of hours in the year increases by 24, so the 29/2 should be forward filled by 28/2.
When rolling from 2016 to 2017 it should be matched by date (month and day) and the 29/2 should just drop out again.

EDIT 2:

so I want sth like this:
    df.forwardcopy(yeartobecopied = 2015, pastedtoyear=2016)
and have the value for day, month and hour align and do a forward fill if pasted to leap year and a drop out of 29/2 if copied from leap year.

EDIT 3:

Apologies, here again explained with input and expected output. Rolling from 2015 to 2016.

Input:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': [0, 1, 2, 3]},
     index = [pd.Timestamp('20150228 09:00:00'),
     pd.Timestamp('20150228 10:00:00'),
     pd.Timestamp('20150301 09:00:00'),
     pd.Timestamp('20150301 10:00:00')])
```

Output:

```
  df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': [0, 1, 0,1, 2, 3]},
     index = [pd.Timestamp('20160228 09:00:00'),
     pd.Timestamp('20160228 10:00:00'),
     pd.Timestamp('20160229 09:00:00'),
     pd.Timestamp('20160229 10:00:00'),
     pd.Timestamp('20160301 09:00:00'),
     pd.Timestamp('20160301 10:00:00')])
```

and then from 2016 to 2017.

Input:

```
  df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': [0, 1, 0,1, 2, 3]},
     index = [pd.Timestamp('20160228 09:00:00'),
     pd.Timestamp('20160228 10:00:00'),
     pd.Timestamp('20160229 09:00:00'),
     pd.Timestamp('20160229 10:00:00'),
     pd.Timestamp('20160301 09:00:00'),
     pd.Timestamp('20160301 10:00:00')])
```

Output:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': [0, 1, 2, 3]},
     index = [pd.Timestamp('20170228 09:00:00'),
     pd.Timestamp('20170228 10:00:00'),
     pd.Timestamp('20170301 09:00:00'),
     pd.Timestamp('20170301 10:00:00')])
```

Comment: if `2015-02-28 10:00:00 `  is the current year, What should be the fill value after one year?

Comment: yes, if 2015-02-28 10:00:00  is the current year then 2016-02-28 10:00:00 should be the same value as 2015-02-28 10:00:00

Comment: Can you given any example of `if I roll forward from say 2015 to 2016 then the number of hours in the year increases by 24`?

Comment: yes thats absolutely correct. See my second edit, hope that makes it clearer

Answer (score 0):

```
In [17]: from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta                                                                                                                                                  

In [22]: df.index = [date + relativedelta(years=1) for date in df.index]                                                                                                                                   

In [23]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[23]: 
                     Value
2014-01-01 09:00:00      0
2014-01-01 10:00:00      1
2014-01-01 11:00:00      2
2014-01-01 12:00:00      3
2014-01-01 13:00:00      4
```

The list comprehension is a workaround because `relativedelta` does not seem to support broadcasting. This should also work with leap year and the like.

Interestingly trying with `pd.Timedelta` works but gives wrong results.

```
In [10]: df.index + pd.Timedelta('1y')                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[10]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2014-01-01 14:49:12', '2014-01-01 15:49:12',
               '2014-01-01 16:49:12', '2014-01-01 17:49:12',
               '2014-01-01 18:49:12'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='H')
In [24]: pd.Timedelta('1y')                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[24]: Timedelta('365 days 05:49:12')
```

The documentation also does not mention supporting intervalls larger than days, but it does not throw an error either.

Comment: thank you. but I dont think that will work 100% because if you copy from a non-leap year you have 8760 hrs to a leap year which has 8784 I somehow need to expand the series and do some sort of fill. no?

Comment: Ah, now I understand your problem. Yes, you are correct. However what should happen to '2016-02-29'? Should this become '2017-03-01'? If so what happens to '2016-12-31'? Should it be dropped? Filling is one thing but what about years after a leap year?

Comment: it should be matched by date and then 2016-02-29 should be filled and when rolled to 2017 dropped again

Comment: And what should '2016-02-29' be filled with? There are no values in 2015 which match by date.